# How to use Google Cloud Pub Sub with Socket.IO node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-cloud-pubsub

How do I use google pubsub with Node.js's Socket.IO. Documentation isn't very good for Node.js. Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google pub/sub and socket io adapter [socket.io-pubsub](https://github.com/elegantmonkeys/socket.io-pubsub)